# Fragment instance in fragment manger is not removing even that fragment got popped up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I have a Fragment with list view. OnItem click of that list view I will replace the fragment's container with the new fragment. The new fragment will have the view pager and fragment state pager adapter. This adapter will create three fragments once. Now, all the five fragments (List fragment, fragment which has the view pager and the three fragments which are created by the fragment state pager adapter) are in the fragment manager. If I came back to the fragment which has list view. All the fragments except the one with list view should be removed from the fragment manager. But, they are not removing.

The problem is, If I click an item in the list view It will create three fragments all the time. And If I do orientation change, the fragment manager is recreating all the fragments. Each time I do orientation change three fragments are getting added to the fragment manager.

Is there any way to remove the fragment associated with view pager when I come back from the view pager fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I think this is your problem:

Every time your orientation changes, you add a new fragment manager transaction to the backstack. When you pop the backstack, you don't go back to the initial state but to another state where you still have the same fragment visible.

There are multiple ways around it. Choose one:

1. Don't add the fragment manager transaction to the backstack when you replace the fragments. When you need to go back to the initial fragment, just replace the contents with the fragment that you want. You can always keep a reference to the fragment in the activity if you don't want to re-create the fragment.
2. Pop the backstack before replacing the fragments and adding another transaction to the backstack. This way you are not accumulating transactions in the backstack. When you pop, the backstack you will always come to the previous state.
3. Name your fragment transaction so you can pop the backstack with `popBackstack("fragmentTransactionName", 0)`  or `popBackStack(transactionId, 0)`
   See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Hope this helps